# Previewing PDF and PowerPoint files with Silverlight/Flash

Tags: flash, silverlight, pdf, powerpoint, page-curl

I'm looking for code or a good control to preview PDFs and PPTs with Silverlight or Flash. It would be great if it has nice page-curl functionality.

We want our customers to be able to have a look at their reports in a spiffy way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas for Silverlight display:

- [PPT Viewer](http://www.codeplex.com/pptx2silverlight)
- [PDF for Silverlight](http://www.amyuni.com/silverlight/index.php)
- [TextGlow](http://blogs.technet.com/gray_knowlton/archive/2009/03/23/textglow-silverlight-open-xml-viewer-source-code-available.aspx)
- [Page Curl](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfbookcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

Flash can only display Jpg images, therefore will need to convert each page of the PDF or PPT to a jpg file, then import these into a flash page turner component.

PDF files can be rasterized or converted to jpg using GhostScript.

PPT files could be printed to PostScript(PS) through Office automation or other library, The PS can then also be converted to jpg using GhostScript.

I have done this in Flash and would assume the same applies for Silverlight.

This is what is required at a low level.

Comment: the best approach is to convert the PDF into an SWF on the server, because it's more performant, probably smaller and preserves resolution independent data ... most simple thing would probably be pdf2swf from swftools (http://www.swftools.org/) ...

Comment: Does the pdf to swf convert the text to selectable text within the swf?