# Silverlight 4.0 PDF Viewer

Tags: silverlight, pdf, silverlight-4.0, stream, viewer

Any free control to view PDF for Silverlight?

or how to view pdf in silverlight from memory stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this question: [Previewing PDF and PowerPoint files with Silverlight/Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224346/previewing-pdf-and-ppt-with-silverlight-flash)

Other maybe useful links:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/23986/85909.aspx#85909

http://www.siberix.com/reporting.html#pdf-sparkle - Costs money though!

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/70573.aspx

You could use this to edit/print to pdf

Try codeplex: http://silverlightpdf.codeplex.com/

Works with Silverlight 3 not used it with Silverlight 4 beta yet.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is that you can just use **HTML brush** to embeded the PDF.

OR you may try http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Can you please post the sample code on how to implement those options browser based app?

Comment: I can't find any example on how use silverpdf.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by using an iframe and HTMLPage.

```
 <iframe id="mediaContainer" style="position:absolute"/>
```

place this iframe in .aspx

and then call your mediacontainer then set its properties.

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement myFrame = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("mediaContainer");
```

Comment: The only problem here for us was that if you wanted to pop a modal information/error dialog from silverlight it would end up beneath that iframe.

Answer (score 3):

[www.netpdftools.com](http://www.netpdftools.com) - SL library for viewing PDFs and extracting/searching text

Answer (score 2):

One option is to convert the PDF pages to PNG using ImageMagick or GhostScript.

It isn't free, but our Silverlight controls can do this on the fly for you using our own PDF Rasterizer.

(Disclaimer: I work here)

http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/silverlight