# How to Load PDF in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I need to prepare proof-of-concept for a silverlight application. For that I need to load PDF in silverlight. I just need to load PDF in browser and allow the user to perform next, previous, stop and pause actions. Anybody can help out.

Answer (score 1):

It can help you...
[Silverlight 4.0 PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467307/silverlight-4-0-pdf-viewer)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/BlendPDFwithSilverlight.aspx