# PDF-viewer for Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 (SilverDox?)

Tags: silverlight, pdf, windows-phone-7

Is there any PDF-viewer control which can be used in a Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 application?

I've found this thread:
[Silverlight 4.0 PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467307/silverlight-4-0-pdf-viewer)

and tried PDFTron's SilverDox but I didn't have any luck because my application crashes with the exception:

> WindowsPhonePanoramaApplication1.dll!WindowsPhonePanoramaApplication1.App.RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object
>   sender,
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs
>   e) Line 109 + 0x5 bytes   C#

..which is quite strange, I think.
However, the SilverDox works in a "normal" (non Phone 7) Silverlight application.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

ComponentOne has a Windows Phone PDF Viewer and it's license-free to use as CTP. There are some performance issues and not the entire spec of PDF is supported (see the documentation) because it parses pdf data into XAML.
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 runs a much more restricted version of Silverlight, therefore a full-fledged Silverlight 4 library might not work if it uses certain calls or objects that are not supported in the SDK.

I highly doubt that there is a free PDF viewing control right now for Windows Phone 7 - Adobe just released its Reader for WP7, so for now that might be the only way to read PDF documents on the device.

Comment: Not that I know of. Seems like for now the only choice for you would be cross-rendering those to HTML or JPEG (with the help of a web service) and sending them back to the app. Or, of course, you can always write your own viewer given that you have time to work with the specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I got an XPS Viewer up and running. For details see [this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/11/rich-display-of-office-files-on-windows.html).

The blog post doesn't mention it, but it actually converts documents to XPS format. The Windows Phone application uses a Silverlight XPS Viewer that I [found here](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/silverlight-xps-source-code/).

Comment: The blog post is about the PDF Converter Service. I need a PDF or XPS viewer-control for WP7. Is that available as a separate product?

Comment: Sorry, that post doesn't go into much detail. I have revised my answer and included a link to the source.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to scale the produced XAML? When the user makes a scale-gesture the whole XAML should be increased or decreased.

Comment: It works on WP7 and scaling is already included, but you will need to implement the gestures.

Comment: Please tell me from where you get XPS viewer

Comment: @Mahantesh, see the seconds link in my answer.

Comment: @Mahantesh as per my answer that is for Silverlight. It works in WP7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Reader is now available on Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.adobe.com/readermobile/2010/10/25/adobe-reader-windows-phone-7/) (since october 2010).

However, for another PDF to XPS/Silverlight approach, [Amyuni PDF for Silverlight](http://amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfsilverlight) (a commercial product) could help.