# pdf viewer sdks for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

As i investigated  that if want to display pdf file content within app, its required to use third party libraries llke [ComponentOne](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2011/05/14/Display-PDFs-in-your-Windows-Phone-7-application.aspx) or silverdox. In [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219990/pdf-viewer-for-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-silverdox) stack over flow discussion concluded that silverdox not suports WP7.

So Please mention the any other third parties are there (free or Paid). mention which is best third party SDK to use in terms of performance beacuse as i know componentone sdk has some performance leaks.

Thanks for valuable time.