# Simulating scroll gesture on windows phone 7 device without any manual event

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to simulate scroll gesture on windows phone 7 device without any manual event?

I want to scroll a PDF document that has been opened in the Adobe PDF viewer automatically on WP7. How can it be done?

Any views or ideas are welcome.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to scroll? A WebBrowser control? A ScrollViewer? Both can be scrolled programmatically.

Comment: Hi @ColinE !! I am trying to scroll a PDF document automatically in one of the PDF viewers.

Comment: What do you mean by PDF viewer exactly - the Adobe Reader application that can be installed?

Comment: @JamieKeeling Hi.. Yes the Adobe Reader application can be installed. But I want to scroll a PDF document opened in it automatically without any manual touch event. How can it be done programmatically?

Comment: @ColinE How can it be done programmatically?

Comment: @PrateekKhurana You can't interact with any other application from your own as the OS does not allow it, nor does it even prodive the ability to do so.

Comment: Hi @ColinE !! Thanks for the reply. But I think I did not explain you correctly. I am currently working on developing a PDF viewer for WP7. Scroll functionality has been added already. Now I want to write some code within the actual development code to scroll automatically for automation testing purpose. I will not use any other application. So there must be some code to automatically scroll without passing any manual event??

Comment: Hi @JamieKeeling !! Thanks for the reply. But I think I did not explain you correctly. I am currently working on developing a PDF viewer for WP7. Scroll functionality has been added already. Now I want to write some code within the actual development code to scroll automatically for automation testing purpose. I will not use any other application. So there must be some code to automatically scroll without passing any manual event??

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe PDF viewer for WP7 is an application. The WP7 architecture does not permit you to control or communicate with any other running application from your own application. Therefore, no, you cannot programmatically scroll a PDF document that the user has opened.

You might want to look at finding a PDF viewer control that you can embed within your application. See this related question:

[PDF-viewer for Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 (SilverDox?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219990/pdf-viewer-for-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-silverdox)

Comment: Hi @ColinE !! Thanks for the reply. But I think I did not explain you correctly. I am currently working on developing a PDF viewer for WP7. Scroll functionality has been added already.                                 Now I want to write some code within the actual development code to scroll automatically for automation testing purpose.                 I will not use any other application.                                 So there must be some code to automatically scroll without passing any manual event??