# Silverlight - Open/View PDF in isolated storage

Tags: pdf, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage, pdf-viewer

I have a silverlight application that runs in a browser and have several pdf files in the isolated storage. I need to open those files. It could be by downloading them and configuring something in order to have pdf files open by default, or having a kind of SilverLight PDF viewer.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See This Link You Got Some Idea For Do This May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392390/how-to-play-swf-file-in-silverlight

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an url, it's a stream from the isolated storage

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of tools available to open PDF in Silverlight. You could use an async load process to load the PDF content as a byte stream and load them in PDF. Have a look at this question [Silverlight 4.0 PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467307/silverlight-4-0-pdf-viewer)